# Is there a way, i dont need to load my Application new, after changes in my Code while develope?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm interested to know if there is a way that I don't always have to restart my whole project after changes in my code?

I know this mechanism from frontend development with Angular.
If I make changes in my code here, I don't have to reload the whole project.

I use Intellj Idea as IDE.
Is there such a mechanism for Java development or plugins for intellj idea?

Comment: If you run your code in debug mode you can reload changes while it's running. There's a "Reload Changed Classes" item in the Run menu.

Comment: *if there is a way that I don't always have to restart my whole project after changes in my code?* ... No , you need to compile the file that you have made changes.